# editing sql table data using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hyperlink

I have the following php code to hyperlink another page to edit whatever data is on the table. When I click the "edit" button it tells me the localhost is not found. Is the code wrong?

`editpage` is the name of the page where I have the edit code.

```
<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">
    <?php echo "<a href='editpage.php?edit=$row[id]'>"?> Edit 
</td>
```

Comment: Make sure you already open apache server and test it again. And you should change your php code like this:
`<a href="editpage.php?edit=.<?php echo $row['id']?>.">Edit`

Comment: did not work.. maybe there is something wrong with another part of my code :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the following page:

```
http://localhost/editpage.php
```

You might need clean up your code:

```
<style>
.ac { text-align: center; }
.vm { vertical-align: middle; }
</style>

<td class="ac vm">
    <a href="editpage.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Edit</a>
</td>
```